# Weird line space in Word due to end-of-row symbol

Tags: microsoft-word, linebreaks

I am trying to write a paragraph in MS word, but, due to some reason, there is a weird blank line which appears on every page, and it seems to cut a paragraph into two, even though I mean it to be one paragraph only. When I click on Show/Hide in Home tab, I see light gray end-of-row markers. Please let me know how I can remove these weird blanks.

> [image]

Comment: "This is the end-of-cell marker. It is a little like the paragraph mark in that it contains paragraph formatting for the last (or only) paragraph in the cell, but it also holds formatting for the cell. The same mark at the end of each row is the (wait for it) end-of-row marker, which serves a similar purpose with regard to row formatting."

Answer (score 0):

You have your text in two different rows and two different cells of a table.

The end of cell marker can replace the paragraph mark. You can place your cursor in front of it and backspace. This is one of the few instances (if not the only instance) where you can erase a paragraph mark.